# Use htaccess to redirect list of tor exit node IPs to a page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, tor

**Edit: Cron was fine, I had forgotten to turn `RewriteEngine On`, leaving this here in case anyone else wants to do the same as I couldn't find a guide anywhere.**

It's been a while since I've used Apache so this is probably just a syntax issue. I'm trying to redirect all [tor](http://www.torproject.org) users to a specific page on my domain (`/tor.php`) in order to inform them that we're running a [hidden service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) and they need to access the site via the hidden service.

As the hidden service will show `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` as 127.0.0.1, I figured I can just grab the tor IP list once a day on a cron, play with it in `sed` and append to my `.htaccess`. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Cron job to get a list of TOR IP addresses and redirect to tor.php

sed -in '/#\ TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK/,/#\ END-TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK/d' /path/to/www/.htaccess
wget -q https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py?ip=my.server.ip.address -O - | sed '/^\#/d' | sed "s/^/RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^/g; s/\./\\\./g; s/$/\$ \[OR\] /g; 1i# TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK" >> /path/to/www/.htaccess
echo "RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^0\.0\.0\.0$" >> /path/to/www/.htaccess
echo "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tor.php$" >> /path/to/www/.htaccess
echo "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tor.css$" >> /path/to/www/.htaccess
echo "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tor.php [R,L]" >> /path/to/www/.htaccess
echo "# END-TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK" >> /path/to/www/.htaccess
```

This removes the old block encased between `# TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK` and `# END-TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK` and adds a new one based on the IP list which looks something like:

```
# TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^103\.4\.16\.118$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^106\.187\.36\.183$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^106\.187\.36\.240$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^106\.187\.37\.158$ [OR]
...
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^99\.230\.106\.155$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^0\.0\.0\.0$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tor.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tor.css$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tor.php [R,L]
# END-TOR-REDIRECT-BLOCK
```

After this I load up Tor Browser and try to navigate to `http://mydomain/phpinfo.php` (this is Apache password protected so this file is not exposed). It loads `phpinfo.php` instead of redirecting me to `tor.php`. The `REMOTE_ADDR` in `phpinfo.php` is in the list of IP addresses in the `.htaccess` file which is supposed to be redirected.

I have `mod_rewrite` enabled so that's not the issue. The `0.0.0.0` rule is there because my `sed`-foo isn't good enough to remember how to append the `[OR]` to all lines except the last. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron was fine, I had forgotten to turn `RewriteEngine On`, leaving this here in case anyone else wants to do the same as I couldn't find a guide anywhere.